# How can I insert the data into the same row in the csv file in C?

Tags: c, sockets, csv

I have written a C program which captures the raw packets in promiscuous mode (client side) writes it into a file  and sends it to the server over the socket. Server processes the packet(tcp,udp,icmp etc) and writes it into a csv file which then be used for analyzing the packets.

My csv file looks like this: (here i haven't displayed the column header name . '0' means udp packet and rest are its header filed)

[image]

but i want my csv file to be like this :

[image]

I am trying to print the client address in the same row , but am not able to do it. Could anybody please guide me to do it.

My server code is:

```
int main()
{
    int new_sockfd,new1_sockfd,x1,x2,log,n;
    int server_len, client_len;
    struct sockaddr_in serveraddress;
    struct sockaddr_in client_address;
    char clntName1[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
    FILE *ta_address;
    int buffsize=1024;
    char buffer2[1024];

    if((new_sockfd = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0))>0)

    printf("\n ******** Interface Server *******\n");    
    printf("\n Socket was created\n");

    serveraddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serveraddress.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    serveraddress.sin_port = ntohs(9735);
    server_len = sizeof(serveraddress);
    bind(new_sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&serveraddress, server_len);

    listen(new_sockfd, 5);
    while(1)
    {
        char ch;

        printf("\n\n Interface Server waiting...\n");

        client_len = sizeof(client_address);
        new1_sockfd = accept(new_sockfd,(struct sockaddr *)&client_address, &client_len);
        if (new1_sockfd==-1)
        { 
            perror("Connection Not Accepted!!"); return(1);
        } 
        else 
        {
            printf("\n Task agent is connected\n");
        }

        //this line is used to print the ip adderss of the client
        if(inet_ntop(AF_INET,&client_address.sin_addr.s_addr,
                     clntName1,sizeof(clntName1))!=NULL)
        {
            ta_address = fopen("final_report.csv","a+");  
            fprintf(ta_address,"%s\n",clntName1);  
            fclose(ta_address);
        } 

        printf("\n Final Report has been generated!!\n\n");

        //this line is used to create a new csv file and 
        log=open("final_report.csv",O_CREAT|O_RDWR|O_APPEND,0777);
        if(log==-1)
        {
            perror("cannot open processed file\n");
            return(1);
        }

        do
        {              
            x1=read(new1_sockfd, buffer2,1024); 
            x2=write(log,buffer2,x1);
        } while (x1>0);

        close(log); 
        close(new1_sockfd);  
    }
}
```

this is the line which is used to display the udp packets as shown in the first image:

```
fprintf(logfile , "%d,%d,%d,%d,%d\n",0,ntohs(udph->source),ntohs(udph->dest),
        ntohs(udph->len),ntohs(udph->check));
```

Comment: What this line: `if((new_sockfd = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0))>0)` did? Perhaps some error message in case of fail must be here?

Comment: creating a socket in the server side

Comment: This `if()` block does nothing. It can be just replaced with `new_sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM,0);` if no need for error check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what's creating that first line:

```
fprintf(ta_address,"%s\n",clntName1);
```

Instead of doing that, store a copy of clntName1 somewhere, and then insert it into the data read into buffer2.  You'll have to break up the lines in buffer2, and then put clntName1 in front of each line with a tab:

```
write(log, clntName1, sizeof(clntName1)) ;
write(log, ",", 1) ;
write(log, pieceofbuffer2, n) ;
```

If you could use buffered files (`FILE *`) this would be a little easier:

```
fprintf(flog, "%s,%s\n", clntName1, pieceofbuffer2_withoutnl) ;
```

buffer2 may have several lines in it.  for instance its contents may be:

```
"0,1985,1985,24,9991\n0,59324,5355,33,48328\n0,54595,1900,141,42243\n"
```

In my example, you break this `buffer2` into pieces.  Each piece being the numbers
before or between newlines.  So you would print out your copy of the client name into the 
long file, then a comma, then the text of one line.

buffer2 never gets the client name inserted to it, but you mix writing client name and pieces of the buffer to the log file.

Comment: how to store the copy of clntName1 sir? The 'client_address' is used by socket to accept the clients port. If you dont mind can you just tell me how do i do it?

Comment: allocate a second char array `char clntNameCpy[INET_ADDRSTRLEN]` and then do a `strcpy(clntNameCpy, clntName1) ;`

Comment: sir sorry for my poor understanding. but am not able to get it. How can i use clntNameCpy in the buffer??

Comment: You are saving various pieces of data to the log file.  So the name doesn't have go into the buffer.  The name only has to go into the log.

Comment: sir could you please help me out in solving this problem. I am unable to use it in my code. Could you please help me out in writing it.

Answer (score 0):

The CSV file is seperated by comma in a column.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values

And in your code you used LineFeed(`\n`) to create a new line. So the IP address cannot be in the same column with the datas you received.

```
fprintf(ta_address,"%s\n",clntName1);
```

You need to use comma instead of LineFeed(`\n`). And because of there are many lines, you should do this in the do...while loop. You may store the IP address in a char array and then link it with buffer2, then write buffer2, it should work then.